# When is a group scheme a twisted form of a Bruhat-Tits model of its generic fiber?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a compact DVR with field of fractions $K$. 
Let $\underline{G}$ be an affine, flat and smooth group scheme defined over $\text{Spec}(R)$, whose generic fiber $G:=\underline{G} \otimes_{\text{Spec}(R)}K$ is (connected) reductive.

My question is:

Under what assumption is $\underline{G}$ isomorphic over some finite etale extension of $R$ to a Bruhat-Tits $R$-model $\underline{G}_{\text{BT}}$ of $G$, stabilizing some simplex in the Bruhat-Tits building associated to $G$ ?

For example, suppose $\underline{G}(R)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G(K)$. May I assume that the Bruhat-Tits model $\underline{G}_{\text{BT}}$ stabilizing a special vertex in the building of $G$ such that $\underline{G}_{\text{BT}}(R) = \underline{G}(R)$ is such a twist of $\underline{G}$ ?

Thank you very much !

Rony

Comment: This question maybe watered down by restricting to the small site of functors:

Comment: Namely: we know by the Bruhat-Tits fixed point Lemma that any compact subgroup of G(K) necessarily fixes a simplex in the building, so if $\underline{G}(R) = \underline{G}_{\text{BT}}(R)$ (for some $\underline{G}_{\text{BT}}$), and this isomorphism holds true for any finite etale extension of $R$, then $H^1_{\text{et}}(R,\underline{G})$ is bijective to $H^1_{\text{et}}(R,\underline{G}_{\text{BT}})$, right ?